# Wordpress wp_head only inserting script when logged as Admin

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a simple script using the `wp_head` action to the head of my Wordpress website. Curiously, the code shows up when I'm logged in as Admin but doesn't show up for regular visitors.

Any idea why?

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
// Add Yieldlove scripts to wp_head()
function child_theme_head_script_yieldlove() {
    if(is_home()) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var yieldlove_site_id = 'xxxx';
        </script><script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn-a.yieldlove.com/yieldlove-bidder.js'></script>

        <script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
        <script>
            var googletag = googletag || {};
            googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var yieldlove_site_id = 'xxx';
        </script><script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn-a.yieldlove.com/yieldlove-bidder.js'></script>

        <script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
        <script>
            var googletag = googletag || {};
            googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_theme_head_script_yieldlove' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was using WP Rocket plugin and it created issues with my JS scripts. I just disabled the JS options.